# Domain of arctan(1/x)

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

I had this as part of a question in an exam. And, I reasoned, even when it's arctan(1/0) (undefined), it is pi/2. And, so I said, domain belongs to all Real Numbers. Why isn't it this

Comment: Because $1/0$ is meaningless. You could define $\arctan(\infty) = \pi/2$, and $\arctan(-\infty) = -\pi/2$, but $1/0$ doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @user61527 : $\;\;\;$ $1/0$ could make sense as [unsigned infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_line). $\:$ (However, arctan of that doesn't make sense.) $\;\;\;$

Comment: $x=0$ is a discontinuity, which isn't included in the domain. The domain of $\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you all for that. I thought I had a stroke of genius when I put all real numbers instead of not equal to 0.

Comment: There is a way to make your idea rigorous.  Consider the space $X = [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] / \sim$, where $-\frac{\pi}{2} \sim \frac{\pi}{2}$ (topologically a circle) and the projective line $Y = \Bbb{R}P^1 \cong \Bbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ (also topologically a circle).  There is a homeomorphism $T: X \to Y$ defined by $T(x) = \tan x$ for $x \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $T(-\frac{\pi}{2}) = T(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \infty$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac1x=+\infty\neq\lim_{x\to0^-}\dfrac1x=-\infty,\qquad\lim_{y\to+\infty}\arctan(y)=\dfrac\pi2\neq\lim_{y\to-\infty}\arctan(y)=-\dfrac\pi2$$ Since the left limit differs from the right limit, the limit does not exist. To exist, the two limits must be equal and finite.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x) = \arctan(1/x)$ is undefined at $x=0$, you cannot assume it is $\pi/2$ at such value of $x$. The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.